# Does $\beta(G)=\alpha'(G)$ always?

Tags: graph-theory

Does there exist a graph where the minimum vertex cover does not equal the size of the maximum matching?

I'm thinking that if it does, then it cannot be a bipartite graph and so it contains an odd cycle.

Comment: Have you tried checking on any non-bipartite graphs? How about $K_3$?

Comment: For bipartite graphs, König's theorem guarantees the equality. So you are right, that a graph must contain a cycle with an odd length, if the equality does NOT hold.

Answer (score 1):

If graph is bipartite, the assertion is konig theorem, nevertheless the assertion is not generally true; counterexample is K3.